# Making linear models in R

Tags: linear

I'm trying to make linear models in R, using the practicing datasets (sim1, sim2, sim3, sim4). So I used this code,

```
mod1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = sim3)
mod1
```

And it printed this one.

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1          x21          x22  
     1.8717      -0.1967       2.8878       4.8057  
        x23  
     2.3596
```

But I have no idea what `x21`, `x22`, `x23` means. Can anyone tell me about it?

Comment: Well, your `x2` variable is a character-valued covariate with four levels. For each level after the third, you get a coefficient. The coefficients are estimates of the formula of your model.